# What does Fn + Shift + Q key combinaton do on an Lenovo IdeaPad laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, lenovo-laptop, function-keys

I accidentally pressed this key combination: `Fn + Shift + Q` on my Lenovo Ideapad S145 laptop and it found out that it toggles between these 2 modes:

[image: First Mode]

[image: Second Mode]

I don't know the meaning of these 2 modes. I tried searching it up on the internet, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This option seems to trigger with Fn + Q. It switches between 2 different performance modes. The one linked to your first image is called "Performance Mode" and prioritizes performance over power usage. The second one is called "Silent Mode" and prioritizes a lower power use, resulting in less performance, usually making the laptop more silent.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I got 3 states - quiet, auto and performance. the power button switches from blue to white to red